# Breaklines in lstset does not work sometimes

Tags: listings

I am including some code into my tex file via `\lstinputlisting[]{}`. Unfortunately sometimes the `breaklines=true`-command does not work. Example:
[image]

In line 65 the linebreak does not work, but in line 70 it works. Why?
My `lstset` is:

```
\lstset{literate=
  {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
  {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
  {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
  {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
  {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
  {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
  {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
  {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
  {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
  {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
  {€}{{\EUR}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1,
  breaklines=true, postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\color{red}\hookrightarrow\space}},
  rulecolor=\color{black}
}
```

Full listing:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bibgerm} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\usepackage{listings}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage[bw,numbered,framed,autolinebreaks]{mcode}
%\usepackage[per-mode=fraction,output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
%\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{bigstrut}
%\usepackage{rotating}

\setlength{\parindent}{0ex}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.5ex plus0.5ex minus0.2ex}
\setlength{\headheight}{26pt}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-0.2in}
\addtolength{\headsep}{0.2in}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.2in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{0.5in}

\renewcommand{\topfraction}{1.0}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{1.0}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.0}

\newcommand{\unit}[1]{\ensuremath{\, \mathrm{#1}}}
\newcommand{\sinc}{\mathrm{sinc}}
\newcommand{\cosc}{\mathrm{cosc}}


\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
def jonswap(self, w, wp = None, alpha = 0.0081, gamma = 3.3, beta = 1.25):

            S.append(alpha*gamma*gamma/elem**5*math.exp(-beta*(wp/elem)**4)*gamma**r)
        return S 
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't sent code snippets. Make complete, compilable (but small!) examples.

Comment: Should I include my (included) code, too?

Comment: You should make a *small* but *complete* example that demonstrates your problem. Use your brain to decide how this is done best (hint: you probably can delete all the literate declarations, and you don't need \lstinputlistings, you can copy a small part of your code directly in a lstlisting environment).

Comment: Only the part to make the problem understandable and reproducable for us. -> http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/

Comment: @Johannes_B: I hope this example is sufficient enough, the first line gets a break, the second not.

Comment: @arc_lupus `breaklines` cannot work if you have no white space in the whole line.

Comment: @yo': Ah, ok, I thought that it will simply break at one suitable point (like `*`). Adding whitespaces solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `breaklines` doesn't take decisions. It has two simple rules for breaking:

1. Don't break the initial indentation (i.e., leave at least something other than whitespace on the line)
2. Break only at whitespace.

Since your line doesn't contain any whitespace, there's no feasible breakpoint whence no break.

Comment: Listings will break at other places too if you add (beside `\breaklines=true` the option `breakatwhitespace=false`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah I didn't know that. Do you plan to make it an answer or should I  improve mine?

Comment: You can add it to your answer.