How to add a line break in bold text in a code listing
I need to bolden some text within a code listing and for that I am using using the following code that uses mathescape=true and \textbf in a lstlisting:
\begin{lstlisting}[language={}, basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},mathescape=true]
regular text
$\textbf{hello hi}$
regular text
\end{lstlisting}

This works fine as it makes hello hi in bold text. But when there is a line break between hello and hi, like this:
$\textbf{hello 
hi}$

The line break is not present in the result. I tried adding a \ but that didn't work either.
$\textbf{hello \\
hi}$

Any idea how to add a line break here?

Refer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237501/breaklines-in-lstset-does-not-work-sometimes

@MadyYuvi The lines are breaking fine in the part of lstlisting that is outside $\textbf{ and }$. The issue is with the part inside $\textbf{ and }$.

you are escaping to math, and $\textbf{hello\\hi}$ wouldn't work outside a listing neither. Use escapechar=$  instead of mathescape=true:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
$\textbf{hello\\hi}$

\begin{lstlisting}[language={}, basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},escapechar=$]
regular text
$\textbf{hello\\hi}$
regular text
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}


(It isn't bold, as you didn't provide an full example that shows your font setup.)I
